# How to create a gradient button in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, gradient

I am trying to create a button similar to this one, I don't have exact colors so using yellow and black.

**Want this**

[image]

**My Code Output**

[image]

here is my code:

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? text;
  double width;
  final Function()? onPressed;
  CustomButton({this.width = 0.8, this.text, this.onPressed});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: CustomTextWidget(
          text: text!,
          textColor: AppColors.BLACK_COLOR,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 1.1,
        )),
        height: ScreenSize.heightSize * 0.08,
        width: width.sw,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: const LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.yellow, Colors.black],
              begin: Alignment.topRight,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
              stops: [0.7, 0.8],
              tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Kindly help how to do this.

Comment: Your `begin` and `end` parameters of the `LinearGradient` are both the same, try setting like `end: Alignment.bottomLeft`

Comment: Work with Container's BoxDecoration shadow property to achieve this effect

Comment: @Ante Bule i tired but it doesn't looks as i want.

Comment: @Prashant are you talking about box shadow?

Comment: Yes bro. BoxShadow property

Comment: but it will give shadow at back of button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you and used [`FractionalOffset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/FractionalOffset-class.html)

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    height: 44.0,
    width: 100,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Colors.yellow,
          Colors.black,
        ],
        begin: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
        end: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
      ),
    ),
    child: const Text('SIGN UP'),
  ),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Alignment is preferred to FractionalOffset, and would work identically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `Linear Gradient` like this:

```
LinearGradient(
   colors: [
       Color.fromARGB(100, 137, 90, 11),
       Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 208, 72)
   ],
   begin: Alignment.topCenter,
   end: Alignment.center,
   stops: [0.0, 0.3],
),
```

**Output:**

[image: Result]

IMO, It looks better.

P.S. You can change `colors` & `stops` property as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for Gradient color in Elevated Button

```
Container(
        height: 44.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.green])),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent, shadowColor: Colors.transparent),
          child: Text('Elevated Button'),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Please don't advertise in your post. Your link tripped our spam detection protocols.

Comment: It's not advertise Sir, It was a link of community where experts are helping to others.